# Can't access return of a method to another method in java?

Tags: java

I have three methods.

```
public class MyProject {

    public static void getArea(double width, double length) {
        double area = (width * length);
        printVolume(area);
    }

    public static double getHeight(double height) {
        return height;
    }

    public static void printVolume (double area) {
        System.out.println(area * height);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          MyProject.getArea(5,6);
          MyProject.getHeight(7);
    }
```

The first method getArea takes two arguments from the main method like this `MyProject.getArea(5, 6)` and sends the value to the `printVolume` method by passing the "area" as argument. Now I also plan to assign value to height by doing `MyProject.getHeight(10)` in the main method. And the printVolume method should just get the height and multiply with the area to print the volume. So far, I can get the value of area inside the printVolume method but I cant access the value of height. How can I access its value? Can I somehow pass it as another argument in the printVolume method? Thank you.

Comment: the height variable in printVolume not exists in this context

the correct would be 

    public static void printVolume (double area, double height) {
        System.out.println(area * height);
    }

Comment: What is the purpose of method `getHeight()`? It does nothing. It just returns its parameter. Why do you need it?

Comment: @Abra getHeight() does nothing but only returns the value of height. It then multiplies with the area to give volume. I am just separating my methods. One just calculates area while the other prints final volume.

Comment: _getHeight() does nothing but only returns the value of height_ No. It returns the value that was passed to it. If the method did not have a parameter, that would make sense. A `get...` method, in general, is used to give access to a private member of a class. Your class, `MyProject` has no members.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, something like this?

```
public class MyProject {
    private static double height;


    public static double getArea(double width, double length) {
        // if you're calling printVolume() separately, there's no need
        // to do it here as well
        return width * length;
        //printVolume(area);
    }

    public static double getHeight() {
        // a getter method should just fetch the value, not set it, use a setter for that
        return height;
    }

    public static void setHeight(double h) {
      height = h;
    }



    public static void printVolume(double area) {
        // this height is referring to the static variable height
        System.out.println(area * height);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          // save area in a variable
          double area = MyProject.getArea(5,6);
          // set the desired height
          MyProject.setHeight(7);
          // call the printVolume() method with the area
          MyProject.printVolume(area);
    }

}
```

Pay attention to the comments. It describes the logic for some of the methods.

Comment: Please don't access static variables using 'this' it's a class variable so should be accessed using class or directly as within the same class you will have visibility to do so.

Comment: You're right. I'm just so used to using `this.xyz` in usual non-static setter methods that I forgot to remove `this` for this case. Edited.